# Finding $X_1$ and $X_2$, the 3D coordinates describing the segment between two skew lines

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, image-processing

Assume you have the coordinates of two detector hits $P_1 (x', y', z')$ and $P_2 (x", y", z")$. How do I get the coordinates of the segment (shortest distance between two skew lines), that  is $X1$ and $X_2$ as shown in the attached figure?

Please show all the steps clearly up to $X_1(x,y,z)$ and $X_2(x,y,z)$. The attached image shows the mid point with star, I want to calculate $X_1$ and $X_2$.

[image]

Comment: Needs a bit more information. Is the segment orthogonal to $u_1$ and $u_2$? How do those directions relate to $P_1$ and $P_2$? Finally, what are your own thoughts on the problem so that people know what language to use. It is not obvious that you know anything about vectors for example.

Comment: Yes, the segment is orthogonal to u1 and u2. P1 and P2 are the hit locations in 3D, while u1 and u2 are two normal vector from the plane with P1 and P2. It is possible to calculate the distance of the segment (shortest distance between skew line). My problem is on how to calculate the coordinates that joins that segment with the two skew lines (u1 and u2) projected normal from the two planes

Comment: Is it not then just the difference in height between $P_1$ and $P_2$ if those two grey planes are orthogonal?

Comment: I don't think so